# How to reset values in to default in flutter bloc when a user logout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I have a application in which multiple users can login so when user logout and login another user without killing application the previous state should not be there
in provider I do something like this

```
  void logOut() {
  _orders = [];
  _isGettingOrders = true;
  _gettingOrdersError = false;
  _gettingOrdersSuccess = false;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

I write a logout function in every provider and call it in logout screen
how can I achieve this bloc

Answer (score 0):

I do this in a large-scale Flutter application and it works great and keeps the architecture clean as well.

1. Introduce one EventBus
2. Listen in the bloc constructor to the EventBus `OnUserLoggedOut` event.
3. Update the bloc state accordingly. For example for an UserBloc you might want to set user=null now that it is logged out.

This approach is clean architecture IMO because it respects the constrain that blocs are not aware of each other, but they are allowed to listen to other events still like a repository or event bus.